# Android: created bitmap has wrong colors

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm porting ios app to android and have issue with bitmap colors while creating it from byte array. This code works perfectly on ios (C# - Xamarin):

```
const int bitsPerComponent = 8;
const int bytePerPixel = 4;
var bytesPerRow = bytePerPixel * BarcodeImageWidth;
var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();

var context = new CGBitmapContext(byteArray,
    BarcodeImageWidth, BarcodeImageHeight,
    bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow,
    colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst);

BarcodeImageView.Image = new UIImage(context.ToImage());
```

[image: ios]

And this code on android makes bitmap with wrong colors:

```
var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(barcode.Width, barcode.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
bitmap.CopyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.Wrap(imageBytes));
barcode.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

[image: android]

Comment: For me it looks like you imageBytes doesn't contain data in argb format...

Comment: @Selvin so what can i do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that by manually created pixel array with skipped first (alpha) byte.

```
int pixelsCount = imageBytes.Length / 4;
int[] pixels = new int[pixelsCount];
for (int i = 0; i < pixelsCount; i++)
{
    var offset = 4 * i;
    int r = imageBytes[offset + 1];
    int g = imageBytes[offset + 2];
    int b = imageBytes[offset + 3];
    pixels[i] = Color.Rgb(r, g, b);
}

var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(pixels, barcode.Width, barcode.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
barcode.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```